# Resize background color when resizing view?

Tags: uiview, size, background-color

I have a view with a background color. How to re-size the background color when the view change its size? My problem is even if the view is bigger, the background color size still the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I thought I had.
When device have rotated, background (background colour) didn't have change its size.
At least it looked as background colour's size didn't change.
I had feeling the situation is stupid. Size of background colour, but not of background? What? I said I felt being mad. But everything looked like background colour keeps it's size despite of device rotation.
I am writing this in attempt to help developers who will google for answer in same circumstances.
Background colour is not separate view, it is a part of its view, so it is absolutely impossible for background colour to have size other than size of its view. Scrutinise hierarchy of your view. You must have some subviews which make you think your background doesn't change size.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.view recursiveDescription]); // compiler will warn it doesn't know method recursiveDescription, it doesn't matter. 

// TODO: remove line above from production code if you don't want to be rejected!
```

will log view's hierarchy of your view controller.